# Google Inbox glanceable newsletters mailchimp Unfortunately we are not able to show any highlights

Tags: newsletter, mailchimp

We are using mailchimp and have a custom template for our newsletters, which is pretty basic. Everything is working okay except for the way it appears in the highlights [glanceable newsletters](https://litmus.com/blog/inbox-by-gmail-update-what-you-need-to-know-about-glanceable-newsletters) preview in Google Inbox app.
It just displays the following message rather than a preview.

`Oops... Unfortunately we are not able to show any highlights for the latest email.`
Then below that a view email link which when you click on it, shows the newsletter fine, as it shows in any other email client.

Any idea how to make a preview show up with glanceable newsletters?